# Create a select metabox that the user can pupolate?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox, plugin-options

I have been working on a plugin that uses text area metaboxes on an options page to populate drop downs in the CPT area. I was with the help of some others able to get the list to show in the select boxes and was able to save the choice to the DB. So far I have been unsuccessful at showing the selected item in the CPT area. Is there an easier way of accomplishing a user editable select box? Or can someone explain why selected is not functioning in this code? I have used var_dump() to verify the variables return the expected outcome. It is like the selected statement is ignored. See code below:

```
<?php
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $options = get_option( 'name' );
        $names = explode( PHP_EOL, $options );
        $name_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'name', true );
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($name_value); echo '</pre>';
        ?>
        <label for="name" class="timeshare-row-title"><?php _e( 'Property Name:', 'timeshare-textdomain' )?></label>
        <select name="name" id="name">
        <?php foreach ( $names as $name ) {
        printf(

                 '<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>',  
            $name,
            selected($name, trim( $name_value ), false),
            $name

            );
        } ?>

        </select>
```

[image: Select Box with var_dump()]

Comment: Are you sure that the `name_value` and `name` are equal with same capital and small letter etc

Comment: @WPTC-Troop Added an image so you could see the admin portion. In answer to your question yes they do match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `$name_value` dump is 10 characters long although Michelle is only 8 characters long. Try adding `trim( $name_value )` to selected function.

Comment: @ville6000-I see what you mean, never even clicked in my head that would have an effect. I added trim as you said, you can see the code above I updated it. But it does not appear to be working.

Comment: Try adding trim to $name also

Comment: @Ville6000-It appears this did the trick, I am going to do more testing to be sure but I think that got it.